# How to perform join for each of the value in array in rethinkdb

Tags: python, join, rethinkdb

I am working on a web platform that serves media content. I am adding 'follow' feature similar to twitter in the platform. Each user must get update from someone they follow in my platform.

I am confused on how to design the database for the 'follow' feature. This is what i tried.

User table containing the info about user also has a follow array.

```
{ 
  id: 'f344cf91-c14f-4772-b481-a5fea8f3107a',
  name: 'something',
  email:'abc@gmail.com",
  username:'adadas',
  password:'234231wwe1'
  follow :  []
}
```

The follow array is used to keep track of the other's **user-ID** whom the current user follows. 
I want to get the posts by the users in the follow array.

Posts are stored in another **post** table.

I want to join user-Id in follow array and the post table to retrieve posts from each user.
I think **for_each** command is to be used to iterate over the array elements. But i am not sure how to join each element of array with table **post**
Can someone please help me in this. Also i am not sure this is the efficient way to implement this kind of a feature in rethinkdb since it requires many joins.

Comment: Your user table seems to lack a user_id field which will make it hard to populate the `follow` list, and to form relationships between user and post tables. On a side note, you shouldn't store the user's password as plaintext - use a salted hash.

Comment: user_id field is in the table. I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
r.table('user').get(USER_ID)('follow').eqJoin(function(row) { return row; }, r.table('post'), {index: 'user_id'})
```

Comment: Will it be efficient if i am following 1000 people. I will be doing 1000 eqJoins to check for new posts right?

Comment: It should be reasonably efficient.  If you're following a lot of people it will be retrieving a lot of posts, but the `eqJoin` shouldn't cause any problems in and of itself.